# Fiddler Web Debugging Proxy's "AutoResponder" feature on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, proxy, fiddler, rewrite

There is a website that I like visiting which uses a Javascript that does not work on Linux with Iceweasel. Looking into the source, I have found a simple way to fix it, so what I would like to do is set up something like [Fiddler2's AutoResponder feature](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp) that will intercept a request for the bad Javascript, returning the fixed Javascript from the local filesystem instead.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Note: The webmaster has refused to use my fixed version of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using GreaseMonkey? Depending on when the JS is loaded (and how it's executed) - that may be the perfect solution.

Comment: Yes, I looked into Greasemonkey, but unfortunately by the time that the Greasemonkey script executes, the error has already occurred.